# How to make this JOIN in Code Igniter (BonFIre)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bonfire

I am having difficulty JOINing 3 tables.

I have following table (Column)

apk_inv_item                     (`item_id`)

apk_inv_category                 (`category_id`)

apk_inv_item_category_defination (`item_id`, `category_id`)

I want to get category ID of the Item from the Item to Category Mapping table.

Here is what I have tried so far.. But it

```
select("apk_inv_item.*, apk_inv_category.inv_category_id")
->join("apk_inv_category", "apk_inv_item_category_defination.inv_category_id
 = apk_inv_category.inv_category_id")
->find_all();
```

But I get `Call to a member function num_rows()` that means query is not right.(Please note that I have tried simple 2 table JOIN with another table for testing and it works, means there is no issue with my MySQL connection or PHP code. Its issue with building that query)

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..

```
  $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('apk_inv_item');
    $this->db->join('apk_inv_category', 'apk_inv_category.category_id= apk_inv_item_category_defination.category_id');
    $this->db->join('apk_inv_item_category_defination', 'apk_inv_item_category_defination.item_id = apk_inv_item.item_id');


    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();

    return $count;
```

Hope its helps.

Comment: I have BonFire flavour of CI and I will use `find_all()` rather than `count_all_results`

Comment: You didn't mentiond, you using  BonFire  CMS . Rather then this hope my syntex is correct.